# How to use Jedis client in Spring Session Redis

Tags: redis, jedis, spring-session, lettuce

How to use Jedis client in Spring Session Redis
Is there a way to use Jedis instead of Lettuce in spring session.
It seems like spring-session-data uses Lettuce by default.
Is there a way to override them?

tried to include jedis client in maven dependency but not sure if spring-session-data-redis and spring-boot-starter-data-redis uses jedis which i included externally and created a bean.